# How to add "WITH" clause to SELECT query with sqlbuilder

Tags: java, singlestore, sqlbuilder

I am using Java and SQLBuilder from healthmarketscience.sqlbuilder and I am trying to add WITH clause to my SELECT query dynamiclly.

My current query build with:

```
selectQuery.addJoins(SelectQuery.JoinType.LEFT_OUTER, Table.joinToQuery);
```

The expected result should be:

`LEFT OUTER JOIN Table WITH(table_convert_subselect=1) ON (...)`

Comment: I doubt `WITH` clause is supported, so you likely have to call `addCustomJoin()` instead.

Comment: how can it help?